# Writing multiple equations in a box

Tags: equations, box

I want to write a set of equations with some text like in the following format[image]

It should have:

1. Box spanning the complete text width
2. Ability to use `enumerate` or some alternative
3. Ability to write equations, in some cases spanning multiple lines (using `align` environment)
4. Should carry over to multiple pages seamlessly

Does anyone have any pointers for me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: → [Package `tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). The package even supports automatic page breaks if needed. Alternative packages like `mdframed` are also available, but I prefer `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\paragraph{Box 1\\}
Local equation describing PTs \dots
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Additive \dots
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        1+1=&2
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    \item Using flalign \dots
    \begin{flalign}
        &1\neq2&
    \end{flalign}
    \item Using flalign without number of equation \dots
    \begin{flalign*}
        &1-1=0&
    \end{flalign*}
    \item Internal \dots
    \begin{align}
        1\neq&2&&
    \end{align}
    \item Evolution \dots{}
    \begin{align}
        1\neq&2
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regards!
Darío

**EDIT**

If you want that continue in the next page, then use `mdframed` package, more simply that `fbox` more `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{mdframed}
\paragraph{Box 1\\}
Local equation describing PTs \dots
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Additive \dots
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        1+1=&2
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    \item Using flalign \dots
    \begin{flalign}
        &1\neq2&
    \end{flalign}
    \item Using flalign without number of equation \dots
    \begin{flalign*}
        &1-1=0&
    \end{flalign*}
    \item Internal \dots
    \begin{align}
        1\neq&2&&
    \end{align}
    \item  \dots
    \begin{flalign}
        1\neq&2
    \end{flalign}
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2-10]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

The example there are three pages (did not enter the screen), but the box entire there is in the all pages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Dario for the detailed answer. This is a beginner solution, but nor perfect - 1. It does not align perfectly with the text width (We can play around with text width, but not an elegant solution) 2. This does not continue to more than 1 page (I updated the question with this)

Comment: Hello! I edited the answer using the package mdframed. More simply and a lot of options, colors and formats.

Comment: You `\fbox` is oversized. You have to reduce the width of the `minipage` by `2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule`. Adding a paragraph before it and using `\noindent` would also be recommended. Manual numbering of elements is also not recommended. And if someone increases `tocdepth` to add the `\paragraph` level to the ToC, the `\\ ` at the end of the argument it also a problem and therefore not recommended.